# How to monitor(look which server made what changes) the master slave replication

Tags: mysql

i have a master slave setup on different ec2 instance and they are perfectly replicating i just wanna know how to check the changes made by the other instances to the database we replicate

Comment: What are you asking about?  The integrity of replication?  Which Replica is ahead of the others?  Whether some node has crashed?  And what version of MySQL are you referring to?

Comment: no like i wanna know which user performed what operations like(select update)on the database

Comment: `SELECTs` are not replicated.  To monitor SELECTs, see the "general log".

Comment: ya exactly i used server_logs to see the changes